# Change page permission using gdb

Tags: linux, gdb

I was playing around with gdb and I'd like to set remove executable privilege from a particular page. How could I go about doing that? I don't need to be able to do that from within gdb, its just that I'd like to change the permission somehow(anything short of modifying the source code of the binary will do).

[EDIT]
Im looking for a solution that works for binaries that are not linked against libc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Even if the binary is not using libc, it *must* execute at least one system call to do anything useful.

What you need to do then is to arrange for correct arguments to be on the stack or in registers (details differ between processors and OSes, and you haven't told us which one you are running on), and then jump (using GDB `jump` command) to the syscal instruction.

E.g. on `Linux/x86_64`, you would put `10` (`__NR_mprotect`) into `%rax`, `addr` into `%rdi`, `len` into `%rsi`, and `3` into `%rdx`. See documentation [here](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/syscall.2.html).

Answer (score 3):

Use mprotect(): http://linux.die.net/man/2/mprotect

You can call it from within gdb, something like `call mprotect(addr, len, 3)` where `3` is the numeric value of `PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE` (at least on my system).

Comment: But that would not work for a binary thats not linked with libc I guess(eg: binary created from assembly that does not use libc.)

Comment: That may be true, but the fact that you're only telling us now that your binary isn't linked with libc makes me sad.

Comment: Apologies, I appreciate your suggestion, thank you for your time.